# Очищает ли метод clear весь вектор, элементы которого имеют вектор стрингов?

Tags: stl, c++

То есть, если `vector<vector<string> > con;` , то `con.clear();` очистит всё элементы и их векторы со строками или же будет утечка памяти?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, удаляет, и при этом корневой вектор вызовет деструкторы объектов членов, которые он хранил.